# How to create GIN index in Django migration

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing, migration, django-migrations

In Django, since version 1.11 we have a class for PostgreSQL `GinIndex` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/). I'd like to create a migration that constructs such index on a `VectorSearchField` I added to one of my tables. So far, I've tried to simply add `db_index=True` to the `VectorSearchField`, but that fails, because it tries to create a B-Tree index (I think) and the `VectorSearchField` values are too long.

I managed to create the index I want by running a `migrations.RunSQL()` migration with:

```
CREATE INDEX entryline_sv_index ON entryline USING GIN (sv);
```

However, I guess, since there is a special `GinIndex` class in Django, maybe there is a way to create such index without executing raw SQL?

Here's a model class:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.search as pg_search

class EntryLine(models.Model):
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length=512, db_index=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    sv = pg_search.SearchVectorField(null=True)  # I want a GIN index on this field.
```

Any idea how to properly create an index for `sv` field in a migration? Or is executing the `CREATE INDEX ...` query the best way?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Haven't yet had a chance to migrate my old manual `CREATE INDEX` codes to the new system introduced in `1.11` but my understanding is

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
import django.contrib.postgres.search as pg_search
    
class EntryLine(models.Model):
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length=512, db_index=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    sv = pg_search.SearchVectorField(null=True) 
    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['sv'])]
```

Is what's required. Raw SQL `CREATE INDEX` statements need not be used any more.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! :) Just didn't know the proper way to use the GinIndex class. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best with your project