# Improve performance of Django PostgreSQL query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Suppose I have the following table:

```
class Word(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                   default=uuid.uuid4,
                   editable=False)
    name = CharField(_('Word'),
                     db_index=True,
                     max_length=250)
```

This table contains around 3 million rows. Content is mainly Cyrillian words.

What I want to accomplish is to search through some predefined list of values. The problem is that words in the table are accented.

Content of tables is like:

```
мо́рква
буря́к
я́блуко
```

But I query without accent.

```
words = ['морква', 'буряк', 'яблуко']

Word.objects.annotated(name_without_accent=Func(
            F('name'),Value('[%s]' % ACCENTS), Value(''),
            function='regexp_replace',
        )).filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(name_without_accent__icontains=w) for w in words], Q()))
```

The problem is that this query on such big table runs very long. An `words` list can contain more elements (around 20-30).

Is there anyway to improve overall performance of querying such big table?
Improve Django query? Tune Postgres? Use some external tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', word)` instead of regexp. And if you do a lot of such queries it would be reasonable to make additional field with unAccent versions of words and make index by that field, because in your situation db_index doesn't give any help it just slows table with reindexing.

Comment: Where should I use `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', word)`?

Comment: In annotation field

Comment: Forgot my previous comment about annotation ((( It was too early in the morning for answering, sorry (((
I think the best solution would be creation of additional field or even additional temporary table

Comment: Did as you told, but still `contains` is very slow. How can I improve it? Query  runs 7 seconds (instead of 65 as earlier).

Comment: 7 seconds even after indexing that field? By, the way if you index it using Django migrations, check in db if it really crates index. Sometimes Django indexing doesn't have effect.

Comment: I use scheme above, just to test that it is working: `Word.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(name__contains=w) for w in words], Q()))`

Comment: I didn't get, do add an additional field with unAccent words?

Comment: No. I just tested whether field comparison will be faster against regex. It is faster, but still slow.

Comment: Tell me more about your use case why do you use Q objects and contains? There can be a string in the 'name' field and part of it could be 'буряк'?

Comment: Установил Gin Index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793987/how-to-create-gin-index-in-django-migration .Безрезультатно.

Comment: да. я копировал запрос из django, потому что там несколько слов. `SELECT "word_ukword"."id", "word_ukword"."name" FROM "word_ukword" WHERE ("word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%морква%' OR "word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%моркві%' OR "word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%моркви%' OR "word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%моркво%' OR "word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%морквою%' OR "word_ukword"."name"::text LIKE '%моркву%')`