# Django Trigram: create gin index and search suggested words in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, trigram

I have model with title and description fields.

I want to create a GIN index for all the words in the title and description field

So I do it the following way using SQL:

STEP1: Create a table with all the words in title and description using simple config

```
CREATE TABLE words AS SELECT word FROM  ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''simple'',COALESCE("articles_article"."title", '''')) || to_tsvector(''simple'',COALESCE("articles_article"."description", '''')) FROM "articles_article"');
```

STEP2: Create GIN index

```
CREATE INDEX words_idx ON words USING GIN (word gin_trgm_ops);
```

STEP3: SEARCH

```
SELECT word, similarity(word, 'sri') AS sml
  FROM words
  WHERE word % 'sri'
  ORDER BY sml DESC, word;

Result:

word  sml
sri 1
srila 0.5
srimad  0.428571
```

How to do this in DJANGO and also i have to keep updating the GIN index

Answer (score 5):

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/) suggest that you install the relevant [`btree_gin_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html) and append the following to the model's `Meta` class:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex

class MyModel(models.Model):
    the_field = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['the_field'])]
```

A relevant answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794092/2996101).

Regarding the updating of the index, [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes) suggests:

> Finally, indexes will become fragmented and unoptimized after some
>   time, especially if the rows in the table are often updated or
>   deleted. In those cases it may be required to perform a [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)
>   leaving you with a balanced and optimized index. However be cautious
>   about reindexing big indexes as write locks are obtained on the parent
>   table. One strategy to achieve the same result on a live site is to
>   build an index concurrently on the same table and columns but with a
>   different name, and then dropping the original index and renaming the
>   new one. This procedure, while much longer, won’t require any long
>   running locks on the live tables.